# Why is "await ..." not the same as "a = ..." followed by "await a"?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

The following code illustrates how to use coroutines with `asyncio`.

The output of `consecutive` and `parallel_fail` is:

```
SLEEP for 2.5 seconds     # 0
back after 2.5 seconds    # 2.5
SLEEP for 2 seconds       # 2.5
back after 2 seconds      # 4.5
```

(printed after 0, 2.5, 2.5 and 4.5 seconds)

And the output of `parallel` is:

```
SLEEP for 2.5 seconds     # 0
SLEEP for 2 seconds       # 0
back after 2 seconds      # 2
back after 2.5 seconds    # 2.5
```

The outputs of `consecutive` and `parallel` are expected.
But why is `parallel_fail` like `consecutive`, and not like `parallel`?

One would expect that `await something` is equivalent to `a = something` followed by `await a`, right?

```py
import asyncio


async def f(n):
    print(f'SLEEP for {n} seconds')
    await asyncio.sleep(n)
    print(f'back after {n} seconds')


async def consecutive():
    print('consecutive:')
    await f(2.5)
    await f(2)


async def parallel():
    print('parallel:')
    a = asyncio.create_task(f(2.5))
    b = asyncio.create_task(f(2))
    await a
    await b


async def parallel_fail():
    print('parallel fail:')
    await asyncio.create_task(f(2.5))
    await asyncio.create_task(f(2))


asyncio.run(consecutive())
print('----------------------')
asyncio.run(parallel())
print('----------------------')
asyncio.run(parallel_fail())
```

Comment: I don't see a problem. In `parallel_fail()` you first wait 2.5 seconds and then 2 seconds. Like the script stated.

Comment: The expected behavior is, that the two waits happen at the same time, just like in `parallel`.

Comment: In `parallel()` you first start task `a` and `b` then you wait for task `a` to finish (meanwhile task `b` finishes, so this `await b` doesn't await for anything). In `parallel_fail()` you create task `f(2.5)`, then await it and after 2.5 seconds you create task `f(2)` and await it.

Comment: Right, so the point is that `a = ...` in `parallel` is not just an assignment, but a function call. Do you want to write an answer? (Otherwise I will.)

Comment: I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour you observe in `parallel()` is as follows:

- create (schedule) task `f(2.5)` and assign the task to variable `a`
- create (schedule) task `f(2)` and assign the task to variable `b`
- await for task `a` to finish (this will take 2.5 seconds)
- *meanwhile* task `b` (that is scheduled) finished after 2 seconds
- `await b` doesn't await for anything - because task  `b` finished

So here you see parallel running.

---

The behaviour you observe in `parallel_fail()` is as follows:

- create (schedule) task `f(2.5)` and immediately await it (this takes 2.5sec)
- afterwards, create (schedule) task `f(2)` and immediately await it (this takes 2sec)

Here you see normal sequential running.